# Explore Spark Execution Plan, number of Stages, etc

Tags: python, apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs, explain

I need to optimize my pyspark code in order to have an execution plan as parallel as possible; I would know if there is a better way than the .explain method (that is unreadable) to explore the DAG, like a "normal" graph object.

For example it would be very useful to know the total number of stages, the number of "first level nodes" of the DAG, etc.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get a more detailed explain plan from catalyst optimizer by adding "True" .. perhaps this is what you are looking for

```
df = spark.range(10)
df.explain(True)
...output...
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
id: bigint
Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Range (0, 10, step=1, splits=8)
```

more detailed you can also access the Spark UI which provides a DAG visualization and breakdown of jobs, stages, tasks, cached objects, executor distribution, and environment variables ... you can access it via url '**driver_node_host:4040**' which is the default port ... docs here for additional configurations => https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-ui